# Unix-How to copy all csv files from D drive into one text file in E drive using command prompt

Tags: unix, command-prompt

I have n `csv` files in D drive. Due to space issues, I want to copy all of these and save the data into one `txt` file. And then put that `txt` file into E drive. How can I do this using `unix` commands?

Answer (score 1):

The command `cat` prints file contents, `*.csv` is a regular expression for all files ending with '.csv', the character `>` directs the output to a target (in this case a file) and `cp` copies files:

```
cat <source directory>/*.csv > <target directory>/<target file>

cp <target directory>/<target file> <backup directory>/<backup file>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the cat command like this, hope it helps.

```
cat scvpath/*.scv > scvdestpath/filename
```